# Apply comment to different post (not the current post)

Tags: posts, custom-field, comments

I'm building a scrolling page website and on that page I have comment form
and some posts from different categories.

Comments applied to wrong post. 
Is there a way to choose the post I want ?

Thanks

Comment: Without knowing why the comments are applied to the wrong post, I don't know how to guess at an answer.

Comment: Please edit your question to display your relevant code and where you are stuck. As written it is too broad to receive an accurate answer.

Comment: It's not a duplicate (I think) since I'm trying to use comment_form($post_id) function and not apply filters.
And "answered" page not giving an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass the post ID you want to target to WordPress' `comment_form()` method.

Here's a [good write up on the comment_form()](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/21/using-the-wordpress-comment-form) method and [here's the codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) on it.

Comment: Checking this! Hope it will work. That's exactly what I need

Comment: No, not working.
I'm posting it to comment_post(52); and then trying to read get_comments(array('post_id' => 52) getting with var_dump - array(0) { }
What can be a problem?
Thanks

Comment: `comment_post` isn't a method, it's an action. The function/signature you want is `comment_form( $args, $post_id );` Reread the first link in my answer.